# Table sorting doesn't work with IsotopeJs

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I am trying to sort my table with IsotopeJs but it isn't working. I followed what has been given in the Isotope documentation but my table doesn't react. Although the documentation used `ul li`, I changed it to a table layout. Besides that, I used a drop-down instead of buttons to sort the table. If selected an option from the drop-down list, the table should sort the data of countries and servers in descending order, that is from high to low, and prices in ascending order. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could check my code and see if I'm doing anything wrong.

Here's the Codepen link: https://codepen.io/zakero/pen/mddagyo
Here's the code:

HTML

```
<h1>Table</h1>

Sort By:
<select id="sorts">
  <option data-sort-value="countries">Most Countries</option>
  <option data-sort-value="servers">Most Servers</option>
  <option data-sort-value="price">Price</option>
</select>


<table class="table-like" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Options</th>
            <th>Countries</th>
            <th>Servers</th>
            <th>Monthly</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Option 1</td>
            <td class="countries">10</td>
            <td class="servers">3000+</td>
            <td class="price">$10.95</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Option 2</td>
            <td class="countries">56</td>
            <td class="servers">3563</td>
            <td class="price">$8.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Option 3</td>
            <td class="countries">34</td>
            <td class="servers">500+</td>
            <td class="price">$6.95</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Option 4</td>
            <td class="countries">23</td>
            <td class="servers">200+</td>
            <td class="price">$14.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Option 5</td>
            <td class="countries">86</td>
            <td class="servers">38</td>
            <td class="price">$5.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Option 6</td>
            <td class="countries">33</td>
            <td class="servers">50</td>
            <td class="price">$12.99</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

table td{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 13px;
}

table tr{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript

```
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

// init Isotope
var $table = $('.table-like').isotope({
  layoutMode: 'vertical',
  getSortData: {
    countries: '.countries parseInt',
    servers: '.servers parseInt',    
    price: '.price parseInt',
    }
  }
});

$('#sorts').select(function() {
  var sortValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-value');
  $table.isotope({ sortBy: sortValue });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problem, the first one is that you have an extra closing bracket for the object that you pass to `.isotope` and second, you're using a [`.select(..)` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event) listener on a `<select>` element, this event listener is triggered when that text of an input is selected not when the value of a `<select>` object is changed. There are a couple of other problems like invalid HTML and using `isotope` directly on a table and using `parseInt` for value that cannot be parsed to integer. Here is a working version of your snippet:

```js
var $table = $('.table-like').isotope({
  layoutMode: 'vertical',
  itemSelector: 'tr',
  getSortData: {
    countries: '.countries parseInt',
    servers: '.servers parseInt',
    price: function(row) {
      return parseFloat($(row).find('.price').text().replace("$", ""))
    },
  }
});

$('#sorts').change(function() {
  var sortValue = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-sort-value');
  $table.isotope({
    sortBy: sortValue
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 13px;
}

table tr {
  text-align: center;
}

table body {
  position: static;
}

td, th {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<h1>Table</h1>

Sort By:
<select id="sorts">
  <option data-sort-value="countries">Most Countries</option>
  <option data-sort-value="servers">Most Servers</option>
  <option data-sort-value="price">Price</option>
</select>


<table class="table-like" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Options</th>
      <th>Countries</th>
      <th>Servers</th>
      <th>Monthly</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Option 1</td>
      <td class="countries">10</td>
      <td class="servers">3000+</td>
      <td class="price">$10.95</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Option 2</td>
      <td class="countries">56</td>
      <td class="servers">3563</td>
      <td class="price">$8.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Option 3</td>
      <td class="countries">34</td>
      <td class="servers">500+</td>
      <td class="price">$6.95</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Option 4</td>
      <td class="countries">23</td>
      <td class="servers">200+</td>
      <td class="price">$14.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Option 5</td>
      <td class="countries">86</td>
      <td class="servers">38</td>
      <td class="price">$5.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Option 6</td>
      <td class="countries">33</td>
      <td class="servers">50</td>
      <td class="price">$12.99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow. It works perfectly mate. Thanks so much. I didn't realize it had so many mistakes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Hey mate, sorry to bother you again. But can you help me with the layout of the table? It changes after the implementation of Isotope and it doesn't look like a table anymore.

Comment: @Zak That is because it is not meant to be used with tables, you should take a look at the examples in their documentation https://isotope.metafizzy.co/#html . In my example I've used `itemSelector: 'tr'` to make it work, this way it affects the rows not the table itself.

Comment: hey. Thanks for coming in to help me. I looked at their documentation but they don't have anything about tables. I didn't find anything concrete. So I tried ```position: relative !important``` in ```table tr{}``` and it does fix the layout issue but then the sorting doesn't take place any more. I can only see the animation that it is about to get sorted but it actually doesn't. It goes back to the default sorting. Any idea on how to fix this? If you want I can create another question so that you can answer it.

Comment: @Zak They don't have examples using tables because this library is not meant to be used on tables. The sorting works by changing the elements' position (in this case `tr` elements), setting `position: relative` will interfere with that. How you fix the layout depends on what you're trying to do, you can probably make this look like a table by setting all `td` and `th` element to have the same size.

Comment: I tried to give all the tds the same size, but somehow "width" doesn't work. I am fixing each and every td separately by padding. I have like 48 rows with 12 tds each. So it's kind of frustrating.

Comment: @Zak I've added some CSS to my example to illustrate a solution.

Comment: Whoa it worked. That's awesome. Can't thank you enough mate.